# How to plot one variable in ggplot?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I'm searching but still can't find an answer to a quite simple question - how can we produce a simple dot plot of one variable with ggplot2 in R?

with `plot` command this is very simple:

```
plot(iris$Sepal.Length, type='p')
```

But when I'm trying to pass one variable to qplot and specifying geom="point", I'm getting an error "Error in UseMethod("scale_dimension")".

[image: Simple one-variable plot]

How can we make a plot like this but with ggplot2?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

You can manually create an index vector with `seq_along`.

```
library(ggplot2)

qplot(seq_along(iris$Sepal.Length), iris$Sepal.Length)
```

[image]

Answer (score 16):

Actually, you are not plotting one variable, but two. X-variable is the order of your data. The answer to what you want based on your example is:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(iris, aes(y = Sepal.Length, x = seq(1, length(iris$Sepal.Length)))) + geom_point()
```

The answer to your question would be closer to this:

```
ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length)) + geom_dotplot()
```

Comment: `ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length)) + geom_dotplot()` is giving me a histogram, not a point plot.

Answer (score 6):

An alternative to using `qplot` and without specifying the `data` param:

```
ggplot(mapping=aes(x=seq_along(iris$Sepal.Length), y=iris$Sepal.Length)) +
    geom_point()
```

or:

```
ggplot() +
    geom_point(aes(x=seq_along(iris$Sepal.Length), y=iris$Sepal.Length))
```

Answer (score 5):

```
require(ggplot2)

x= seq(1,length(iris$Sepal.Length))
Sepal.Length= iris$Sepal.Length

data <- data.frame(x,Sepal.Length)

ggplot(data) + geom_point(aes(x=x,y=Sepal.Length))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
library(ggplot2)
qplot(1:nrow(iris), Sepal.Length, data = iris, xlab = "Index")
```

or

```
ggplot(data = iris, aes(x = 1:nrow(iris), y = Sepal.Length)) +
    geom_point() +
    labs(x = "Index")
```