# Pipe a single variable (i.e. a vector) to a ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

We can see how to [plot a single variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13837565/how-to-plot-one-variable-in-ggplot) (along with its index).

How can we pipe to a ggplot?

#### Example

Since

```
library(ggplot2)

qplot(seq_along(iris$Sepal.Length), iris$Sepal.Length)
```

yields

[image]

I expected

```
iris$Sepal.Length %>%  { qplot(seq_along(.), .) }
```

to yield the same. But

```
Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale
```

#### Question

How do we pipe a single variable to a ggplot?

Answer (score 2):

Seems to get it working you need to explicitly `print` it when inside a chain.

```
library(magrittr)
library(ggplot2)

iris$Sepal.Length %>% {print(qplot(seq_along(.), .))}
```

[image]

Comment: Is it really weird that it works with print, but errors without, or is it just me?

Comment: Yes, it is weird that it returns an error without `print`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code

```
library(tidyverse)

iris %>% ggplot(aes(seq_along(Sepal.Length), Sepal.Length))+
  geom_point() + theme_bw()+
  labs(title="Plot of Sepal length",x="Sepal.Length seq", y = "Sepal.Length")
```