# ggplot qplot (quick plot) with fill?

Tags: r, ggplot2

How do you do a quick plot (i.e.[`qplot`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13837888/5783745)) with fill?

I've tried

```
iris %>% qplot(Sepal.Length, fill = Species)
Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'Sepal.Length' not found
```

and

```
iris %>% qplot(seq_along(Sepal.Length), Sepal.Length, fill = Species)
Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'Sepal.Length' not found
```

But no luck.

Comment: `qplot(Sepal.Length, fill = Species, data=iris)`

Comment: @Edward sorry I asked an ambiguous question. I was after the equivalent of `qplot(seq_along(iris$Sepal.Length), iris$Sepal.Length)` but with Species as the fill. Really appreciate the help!

Comment: No problem. Your questions are always challenging. Keeps the brain working. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking to plot a histogram and colour by species, pass Species to the colour argument.

```
qplot(data=iris, x=Sepal.Length, fill=Species)
```

[image]

Otherwise, if you were looking to plot points:

```
qplot(data=iris, x=seq_along(Sepal.Length), y=Sepal.Length, colour=Species)
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The error code is because of the `%>%`.

The pipe doesn't work because it by default places the lhs as the first argument in the rhs, in the case of qplot, this is `x`, rather than `data`. If you still wanted to use `%>%`, you would need to specify which argument it is to pipe to:

```
iris %>% qplot(data =., Sepal.Length, fill = Species)
```

and, in your second version, but with @sahwahn's correction

```
iris %>% qplot(data=., seq_along(Sepal.Length), Sepal.Length, color = Species)
```